# Insect(Ant?) Species Identification - location: Singapore

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

[image: Unknown arthropod with weaver ant]

I saw this arthropod (I am not sure if it's an insect) on November 11 at 10:57, at the Berlayer Creek Boardwalk in Singapore. The Berlayer Creek is a mangrove creek flowing towards the sea. This ant-like arthropod was jaw-locked with a weaver ant for 5 minutes or more, and I found them on the wooden partition that separated the bushes and trees from the boardwalk. Both the weaver ants and the unidentified animal is about 1.2 to 1.5 cm long (head to tip of abdomen)

Does anyone know what it is, and maybe even what was it doing?

Comment: Can you please tell much more information about this insect like no. Of legs , body structure, winged or not

Answer (score 2):

I see three ants here: two seem to be of the same species (in red) and are somehow in a fight ([usual ant business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant#Behaviour_and_ecology)) with another, larger ant species (in blue):

[image: three ants outlined]

All three have an [ant-characteristic habitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant#Morphology):

- a flattened head with large eyes and strong mandibles
- long (elbowed) antenna and legs
- a distinct thorax
- a petiole (connects thorax and abdomen)
- a distinct, segmented (and usually large) abdomen

... which you already correctly identified for two of them (the "weaver ants").